# How do I keep the test size constant in cross validation using train_test_split?

Tags: python, csv, for-loop, scikit-learn, svm

I am working with a matrix `X` and a label for each row in this matrix `y`. 
`X` is defined as:

```
df = pd.read_csv("./data/svm_matrix_0.csv", sep=',',header=None, encoding="ISO-8859-1")
df2 = df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
X = df_2.values
```

`y` is defined as:

```
df = pd.read_csv('./data/Step7_final.csv', index_col=False, encoding="ISO-8859-1")  
y = df.iloc[:, 1].values
```

Then I apply machine learning SVM with:

```
clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=1)    #specify classifier
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2)  #splitting randomly the training and test data
clf.fit(X_train,y_train)   #training of machine
```

Now, I would like to vary the `X_train` size and calculate the train and test error for each value of `X_train` with:

```
test_error = clf.score(X_test, y_test) 
train_error = clf.score(X_train, y_train)
```

The `X_train` should increase in size (for example 15 different values) and then the values should be stored in a dictionary in the form of: `{X_train size: (test_error, train_error)}`.

I tried:

```
array = [0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3, 0.35, 0.4, 0.45, 0.5, 0.55, 0.6, 0.65, 0.7, 0.75, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9]
dicto = {}
for i in array: 
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = i)
    clf.fit(X_train,y_train)   
    test = clf.score(X_test, y_test) 
    train = clf.score(X_train, y_train)
    dicto[i] = test, train

print(dicto)
```

But it is not working since I am also varying the `X_test`. Does somebody know how to adapt my code that it varies only the size of `X_train` (so that the errors will be calculated at an increasing total data set size)?

Comment: I don't get your question, do you want to keep your test data size constant?

Comment: Yes my test data size should be a constant, but my training data size should vary from a low to a high value. I want to create a learning curve ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is separate the test data first ...

```
X_train_prev, X_test_prev, y_train_prev, y_test_prev = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2)
```

Now run the for loop changing the train size but testing on the **previous test data*

like this -

```
array = [0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3, 0.35, 0.4, 0.45, 0.5, 0.55, 0.6, 0.65, 0.7, 0.75, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9]
dicto = {}
for i in array: 
    X_train, _, y_train, _ = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = i)
    clf.fit(X_train,y_train)   
    #use the previous test data...
    test = clf.score(X_test_prev, y_test_prev) 
    train = clf.score(X_train, y_train)
    dicto[i] = test, train

print(dicto)
```

But note that what I've done might reduce the model metric score in unseen data as the data is random, we are contaminating the test data too. So what you can do to avoid it is split on the train data, so that your test data remains separated!!

like this (the line in the for loop)-

```
X_train, _, y_train, _ = train_test_split(X_train_prev, y_train_prev, test_size = i)
```

Comment: You are a genius hashcode55! This worked for me, you helped me a lot! Thank you!